# Why do lambdas work without declaration of the variable you're using in it? (Java)

Tags: java, list, generics, lambda

Here is an example of code that seems to be working but I don't get why:

```
public static void replaceElements(List<Integer> list, int operator) {
    list.replaceAll(element -> element % operator);
}
```

How does Java know that the variable element means an element of list? And why does the replaceAll method work although the javadoc says the argument has to be a unary operator?:

```
default void replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)
```

I tried to understand it by debugging step by step but it didn't help much. Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does Java know that the variable element means an element of list?

It doesn't care that it's an element *of the list*, but because the `List` interface is declared as `List<E>`, where `E` is the type of the elements, when the `replaceAll` method declares that it takes a `UnaryOperator<E>`, the Java compiler can reason that you must pass a `UnaryOperator<Integer>` to it.

> the javadoc says the argument has to be a unary operator

Since the compiler knows that you *do* need a `UnaryOperator<Integer>`, and `UnaryOperator` has only a single abstract method (called `apply`), it tries to see whether the lambda you provided matches the signature of that method:

- the compiler wants a `UnaryOperator<Integer>`
- the compiler tries to match `Integer apply(Integer)` (a method that takes an `Integer` as an argument and returns an `Integer`)
- the compiler looks at your lambda, which takes one argument `element`, and sees that if it infers `Integer element`, then the value of the lambda expression will also be an `Integer`, which matches, so it converts your lambda into the equivalent of this code:

  ```java
  new UnaryOperator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    Integer apply(Integer element) {
      return element % operator;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot, especially the last bit of equivalent code! :)

Answer (score 2):

`UnaryOperator` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), hence *"instances of functional interfaces can be created with lambda expressions"*.

> How does Java know that the variable element means an element of list?

It doesn't. All it knows is that you've passed a lambda that takes an input `element` and returns a result, and that the type is inferred from the generic type argument as being `Integer`. It is the `List` itself that iterates over its elements and applies this lambda on each one:

```
default void replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(operator);
    final ListIterator<E> li = this.listIterator();
    while (li.hasNext()) {
        li.set(operator.apply(li.next()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful! Can you give like awards or something here like on reddit? :'D